# Не запоминает настройки и не работает композер

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains

При каждом открытии проекта у меня слетает уровень языка до 5.4 кажется. Я пишу на 5.6. Это довольно неудобно, т.к. сразу начинает подчеркивать некоторые места вроде генераторов и констант-массивов инициализированных в месте объявления. Приходится каждый раз указывать что надо поднять уровень до 5.6. Это уже надоело. Почему он не сохраняет?

И еще композер упорно не работает из IDE. В принципе композер у меня нормально работает из консоли, но было бы конечно удобно не лезть каждый раз туда, а нажать одну кнопку для установки/обновления пакетов. Но при попытке это сделать пишет "Failed to install packages. Full output". А в "Full output" - абракадабра нечитабельная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пути в настройках указывал. Композер установлен без composer.phar.

upd. И еще одну странную багу последнее время заметил: Когда я запускаю композер из консоли, но у меня включена отладка через xdebug (а она у меня постоянно включена) у меня делается остановка на какой-то точке останова (хотя ни одной нет) и композер не обновляет дальше пока F5 не нажму. Тоже очень странно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- При каждом открытии проекта у меня слетает уровень языка до 5.4
  кажется

Проверьте, какие требования к версии PHP у вас указаны в composer.json т.к. PhpStorm может автоматически брать оттуда эту настройку.

- И еще композер упорно не работает из IDE

Какую версию PhpStorm вы используете? Делали ли вы операцию Tools > Composer > Init Composer?

- И еще одну странную багу последнее время заметил: Когда я запускаю композер из консоли, но у меня включена отладка через xdebug (а она у меня постоянно включена) у меня делается остановка на какой-то точке останова (хотя ни одной нет) и композер не обновляет дальше пока F5 не нажму. Тоже очень странно...

Где именно нажимаете F5? В браузере? И где именно происходит остановка выполнения кода?

Comment: 1. Вот это помогло, спасибо. В composer.json был 5.4, я даже не видел. Не думал что он на это смотрит.

2. 2017.2.4, не делал. Композер инициализировал из консоли. А сейчас уже поздно делать.

3. Зачем в браузере? В IDE. Там же точка останова падает.

Comment: Вот кстати скриншот той самой точки останова на которой падает. Я не знаю вообще где это и я такую не ставил. Не знаю как ее снять - она не снимается. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDMwh.png

Comment: Спасибо! Попробовать Init Composer всё же стоит.А что происходит если запустить ту же самую команду, что мы видим в окне с абракадаброй, в командной строке?

Comment: 1. Если я запущу заново инит разве он мне не затрет мой composer.json? Зачем это теперь? 
2. Нормально выполняется, за исключением того что как я уже сказал - если активна отладка xdebug (я ее практически не выключаю, все равно все время нужна) то останавливается на той странной точке останова, после чего когда я жму "продолжить" - обновляет нормально.

Comment: Касательно Composer.phar - кажется, проблема в Xdebug: аналогичные обсуждения можно найти в интернете по тексту ошибки https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5400
Composer.json никто, конечно, не затрёт и это совсем не обязательно. :-) Эта опция просто позволит PhpStorm управлять пакетами и автоматически исключать поддиректории vendor, добавляя их в include path.

Comment: Если честно я вообще не знаю в чем разница между обычным композером и этим фаром. Но из консоли я пишу просто `compose update` (etc) и все работает. А он походу пытается использовать фар. Хотя в настройках IDE стоит именно использование "не фар". Что ж за фигня такая?

Comment: А что внутри этого bat-файла?

Comment: `@"%PHP_BIN%" -d output_buffering=0 "%PHP_DIR%composer.phar" %* 
`

Comment: Вот отсюда composer.phar и берётся.

Comment: Все-таки вы были правы. Я сейчас в настройках выбрал composer.phar и поставил галку "скачать с офф сайта", он его выкачал в папку проекта и с ним стал нормально работать. Мне все-таки очень интересно чем отличается composer от composer.phar? Насколько я понял (посмотрев содержимое) composer.phar это просто php скрипт, который надо выполнять с помощью собственно php. А вот что такое composer без фара? Не знаю где его искать... Может это и есть тот самый composer.bat внутри вызывающий тот же самый composer.phar?

Answer (score 1):

в настройках Storm'a 
**languages & Frameworks > PHP > Composer**
убрать галку **Synchronize IDE Settings with composer.json**, тогда настройка версии языка не будет подтягиваться из композера *(в моем случае в композере >= 5.4.0, тогда как проект написан на 7.1)*